# Security EnterpriseLibrary Logging Block using IIS

Tags: c#, logging, enterprise-library-5

I am using the EnterpriseLibrary Logging block and the application is now being deployed to the live environment, I need to make sure that the security is set very high when the website is running live.

But the problem I am now having is nothing is being logged, EventLog or Rolling Files in the Add_Data directory.  If I set the account the LocalSystem it works fine.

Is there any documentation that explains the EnterpriseLibrary Logging Block and the security settings required for each listener?

Comment: what account were you using when it failed? and what sort of access did it have? When you set the account was that on the app pool?

Comment: I'm after the documentation for security with the EnterpriseLibrary block, but can't find it.

It' seasy to tinker tand play until you think you have got it right, but I need to supply this to our environment team, and the only way I can be sure it is right is the official documentation which I can not find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the following:

Deployment and Operations

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664471(v=pandp.50).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664471%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx)

Deploying Enterprise Library

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664755(v=pandp.50).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664755%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx)

Enabling Instrumentation

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664754(v=pandp.50).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664754%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx)